# web api default action selector

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have web api 1 in my project. I can't use  web api 2. This is my route config

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "images  api",
        routeTemplate: "api/objects/{objectId}/{controller}/{action}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Images" });
```

I would like that post request hit post action of my ImagesController (action is named Post), and that get request hit method named Get. In both cases I get 404. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "images  api",
    routeTemplate: "api/objects/{objectId}/{controller}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Images" });
```

Just excluded action from routetemplate.